# How to Change the Default Command That make Executes?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

By default, when running `make` to compile a C source code file named `prog.c`

```
make prog
```

the default command that executes is

```
cc     prog.c   -o prog
```

Sometimes I really need to include some additional flags. I know that when there are no *Makefiles*, `make` relies on some environment variables.

On *Ubuntu 14.04*, how to configure these variables to change the command that gets executed by default?

Step by step answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no makefile is present (or no rule exists in that makefile) make relies on a default built-in database of rules. Run `make -p` to get make to spit out all the rules it knows about (in the no makefile case that will be the default ones).

When you look at that list you will find a pattern rule for building C source into object files or executables. Those rules have variables in them (like `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, etc.) that can be used to control exactly what you are trying to. That's why they are there (and are why that default command has such funny spacing, in case you ever wondered about that).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but more details would be really appreciated! How to configure these variables exactly?

Comment: They are environment variables. Either set (and export) them in your shell or set them on the make command line. (Either before the command to set them in the environment or after the command to use make's feature of command line argument setting.)